# Datetime format problems

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, format

I'm having problems converting a dateTime from one format to another.

```
Mon 13 Jun 2016 10:00
```

should become

```
13/06/2016 10:00:00
```

However, I'm having problems with the hours minutes & seconds (Yes I realise the seconds are not supplied - so that might be causing formatting problems)

Here's what I've got so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import datetime

def convertDateString(s): 
  d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%a %d %b %Y")

  # return "{dt.day}/{dt:%m}/{dt.year}".format(dt = datetime.date(d.year, d.month, d.day)) # no time, but works fine
return "{dt.day}/{dt:%m}/{dt.year} {dt:%H}:{dt:%M}:{dt:%S}".format(dt =     datetime.date(d.year, d.month, d.day))

# print convertDateString("Mon 13 Jun 2016") # works fine, but ignores time
print convertDateString("Mon 13 Jun 2016 10:00:00")
```

which gives ValueError: unconverted data remains:  10:00:00

Can someone please point out where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out !

```
# Mon 13 Jun 2016 10:00     # in
# 13/6/2016 10:00:00        # out
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%a %d %b %Y %H:%M")
return d.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```